# Is it possible to derive the formula of the conic sections such as ellipse,hyperbola etc using linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, conic-sections

Similar to how we can get an eqn. of a line by dotting a vector between two points with it's perpendicular vector

i.e: $(a,b) \cdot (x-x_o,y-y_o)$=$ax+by-ax_o-by_o$

Comment: Have you seen the [matrix representation of a conic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Matrix_notation)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are related questions such as [Conic Sections with Matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585215/conic-sections-with-matrices) in which we find out that the vector equations of conics are typically put into the form something like

$$ \newcommand{x}{\mathbf x}\newcommand{xhat}{\hat{\mathbf{ x}}}\newcommand{L}{\mathbf h}\newcommand{T}{^{\sf T}} \newcommand{p}{\mathbf p}
\x\T A \x - 2\L\T\x + f = 0, \tag1$$

where $\x$ and $\L$ are $2\times1$ vectors, $A$ is a $2\times2$ matrix, and $f$ is a scalar. There are several variations on this depending on how you want to define and label the constant parts, but the basic idea is the sum of a quadratic form in $\x,$ a linear map $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ over $\x,$ and a scalar.

I strongly suspect this is not a complete answer yet because you might like to see how to get such an equation from a geometric definition of a conic
Now, much as your example produced the equation of a line from the fact that two points determine a line,
we can use geometric facts to derive the equations of the conic sections
This is what I have time for at the moment, but I may want to expand on it.

Let's try a parabola. To keep the equations simpler, assume the $y$-axis is the directrix. Then the distance from the directrix to a point $\x$ in the half plane $x > 0$ is
$\xhat\T \x$ where $\xhat = (1,0)\T$ is the unit vector in the positive $x$ direction.
The square of the distance on either side of the $y$ axis is therefore
$$(\xhat\T \x)^2 = (\x\T \xhat)(\xhat\T \x) = 
\x\T \begin{pmatrix} 1&0 \\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix} \x.
$$

Let $\p$ (a point with $x>0$) be the focus of the parabola.
Then the square of the distance from $\p$ to $\x$ is
$$(\x - \p)\T (\x - \p) = \x\T\x - 2\p\T\x + \p\T\p.$$

The equation of a parabola on the right side of the $y$ axis should set the squares of the two distances equal, so we have
$$ \x\T\x - 2\p\T\x + \p\T\p
 = \x\T \begin{pmatrix} 1&0 \\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix} \x,\tag2$$
which is equivalent to $\x\T A \x + 2\L\T\x + f = 0$ (Equation $(1)$)
where 
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0&0 \\ 0&1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad
\L = \p, \quad \text{and}\quad  f = \p\T \p.$$
For example, if $\p = (2,0)\T$ this equation works out to 
$y^2 - 4x + 4 = 0.$

But [an ellipse or hyperbola also has a directrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConicSectionDirectrix.html)
(two of them, in fact), and we can generalize Equation $(2)$ to
$$ \x\T\x - 2\p\T\x + \p\T\p
 = \rho^2 \x\T \begin{pmatrix} 1&0 \\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix} \x. \tag3$$

Equation $(3)$ is equivalent to Equation $(1)$ with
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 - \rho^2 &0 \\ 0&1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad
\L = \p, \quad \text{and}\quad  f = \p\T \p.$$
If $\p = (2,0)\T$ this works out to 
$y^2  + (1 - \rho^2)x^2 - 4x + 4 = 0,$
which is an ellipse when $\rho < 1,$ a parabola when $\rho = 1,$ 
and a hyperbola when $\rho > 1.$

A circle of radius $r$ about $\p$ of course is given by 
$$(\x - \p)\T (\x - \p) = \x\T\x - 2\p\T\x + \p\T\p = r^2,$$
which is equivalent to Equation $(1)$ with
$$A = I, \quad \L = \p, \quad \text{and}\quad  f = \p\T \p - r^2.$$

Of course equations can also be derived for a directrix that  might be at any angle and might not pass through the origin.
There are just more parameters to deal with in the general case.

---

There's another form of the vector equations of a conic in which we use three-dimensional vectors instead of two-dimensional vectors.
Then the general equation is
$$ \x\T A \x = 0 $$
where $A$ is a $3\times3$ matrix.
You can get the two-dimensional coordinates of a conic by restricting $\x$
to vectors of the form $(x, y, 1)\T.$
For example, see the question
[how to simplify a general plane conic section's equation by linear algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538730/how-to-simplify-a-general-plane-conic-sections-equation-by-linear-algebra)
The two forms of the equation are related to each other as explained in an answer to [Projective conic section](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2055752/projective-conic-section).